# How can I have WebStorm open as my default Chrome text editor?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, webstorm

I'm running a local React app. If an exception is thrown, my Chrome browser looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the error, line 115 for example, it opens up the file in Sublime text editor. I never configured this, it seems to be that Sublime text editor is somehow associated as the default editor.

What I would like is if I click on line 115 on my Chrome browser, it opens up in WebStorm instead (where I'm already doing development and debugging).

Is this possible?

Comment: What's your `$EDITOR` set to?

Comment: Where is this setting? Is this a Webstorm setting or a Chrome setting? If so, where can I find / edit it?

Comment: neither WebStorm nor Chrome; you must have `REACT_EDITOR` environment variable set to `sublime`; try changing it to `webstorm` (or whatever the cmd launcher you run WebStorm with is called). See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration, `REACT_EDITOR`

Comment: @lena That's what I meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was setting:

```
REACT_EDITOR = "/usr/local/bin/webstorm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside setting `REACT_EDITOR` you should also remember to install launcher in Webstorm: `Help -> Create command-line Launcher`

Comment: `Create command-line Launcher` does not exist on windows